# Percentage "%" in format string

Tags: format

```
(format "Hard-coded value is 100\% and the variable is %s" "50\\%")
```

Returns

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid format operation %a")
  format("Hard-coded value is 100% and the variable is %s" "50%")
  eval((format "Hard-coded value is 100% and the variable is %s" "50%") nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

(Note how in the debugger output, the command has the "%" escaped)

How in heaven can I use a string with a percentage in it?

Comment: I think it's `%%`.

Comment: Elisp manual, node [Formatting Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html). You can get to that just by using `C-h i`, choosing the Elisp manual, and `i format RET`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed `%%`. If you type `C-h f format <RET>` you'll pull up the documentation for the `format` function, which states:

```
Use %% to put a single % into the output.
```

Thus:

```
(format "Hard-coded value is 100%% and the variable is %s" "50%")
```

(the `%` signs never need to be escaped with backslashes).